# windows is located in /dev/sda2 but grub menu shows /dev/sda1 ,i can't boot to windows loop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

i had windows installed ,and tried dual booting with Ubuntu like in this video :
https://youtu.be/G28jfXt9EaI
after ubuntu installation was done , i tried booting to windows but
when selecting Windows from GRUB, the screen goes black, then loops back to GRUB selection, as if I never selected Windows
i then realized windows is installed in /dev/sda2 while grub shows it's in /dev/sda1
and when i run `sudo update-grup` i get this error: [image]

Comment: Windows bootloader is likely in /dev/sda1, which is Windows boot partition. Please don't post screenshot of text, copy/paste the text itself.

Comment: What grub boots for Windows is from the EFI partition, so sda1.  That is probably not the problem.  Please add the contents of /etc/default/grub to your original post, might be a syntax error somewhere. cat -n /boot/grub/grub.cfg and look at line 327, where the error seems to have occurred and post around that line if you cannot figure out what the syntax error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Use second option on the page load the Ubuntu live Cd and choose "try without install" -> then open terminal and type these commands one after one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update

sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: i didn't install ubuntu from a cd ,i installed it from a usb 
will this work the same ?

Comment: Yes it will work , just choose try without install. you can also install it on your system , but if you like to choose repair filesystem it can't does on a mount system , so from CD or USB.